# How to do multithreading in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use multithreading using node js. I have created node js app where based on user id I want to set up an indivisual thread. 
Please let me know how to do it with small code example in node js.

**NOTE: I need small code example to explain.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

node.js is per concept single-threaded but you can use for example the npm package [webworker treads](https://npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads)

Comment: It didn't helped me that much but got core idea of how its not possible at large scale in node js.